# Azure- domain randomly stop working and gives issue as "The service is unavailable."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have Hosted our site in Azure ( Azure Website ) and configured trafic manager for load balancing and also configured wildcard subdomain to us Nth number of sudbomain pointed to this site.

From last few days i am facing issue like, Randomly approx 5 times in an hour i got 503 (service not available) error and soon working fine itself.

I have checked azure service status also and its saying all services are normal and running.

can anyone tell me what reason should be possible for this happening. is their any setting in Azure to resolve this OR is this issue of overload.

issue is like

[image]

can anyone please help to solve this issue.??

Comment: If you continue to see this open a support ticket. Does this issue happen only via Traffic Manager? Do you get the same if you request the Website directly? What tier is your Website running (Free?)

Comment: Your site may be recycling due to very high CPU/memory usage and/or repeated exceptions. This is typically due to bugs or more traffic than the machine can manage. The same thing happens with IIS when a site misbehaves. Check your logs (or add logging if you don't have already) to see what happens around the time you get a 503.

Comment: + for recycling, go this on each deployment IIS was reclycling and everything was down